Python: 3-sigma "anomaly" detector of order quantity and lines
I'm wanting to analyze transactional data from an e-commerce context, where the focus is on detecting atypical activities in order patterns. The data is grouped by a customer identifier, SoldTo, and for each group, we apply a straightforward statistical technique to detect anomalies based on the order quantities and line counts. Specifically, the steps involve:

Data Preparation: Ensuring the date column (Created_on) is in the
correct format.
Grouping Data: Grouping the data by the SoldTo field
to isolate the transactions for each customer. Rolling Window
Calculations: For each group, applying rolling window calculations
to compute rolling averages and standard deviations for order
quantities and line counts.
Apply 3-Sigma Rule Application: Using the 3-sigma rule to identify transactions that deviate significantly from the norm, marking these as atypical or suspicious.
Independent Processing: Processing each customer group (SoldTo) independently to
ensure that the detection mechanism is not influenced by data from
other customers. Combining Results: After processing, we write this
data to a .csv file.

My issue:  As a test, I feed ONE known individual SoldTo, having anomalous lines and the code works to detect the anomalous lines, as intended!   But when I introduce more than a single SoldTo including those known anomalous lines, they are no longer detected.  Why would this be?
Here's what I've tried using my code alongside (what I hope will be) two  convenient-to-load-data set/s (one having only a single SoldTo where the my code will detect known anomalous transactions-- and another data set having (2) SoldTo's <- my code no longer works to detect known anomalous lines when 2+ Soldto's are used together...
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(fraud)

df['Created_on'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Created_on'])

# Group by 'SoldTo' and 'Created_on'
grouped = df.groupby(['SoldTo', 'Created_on', 'Sales_Doc']).agg(
    total_quantity=('Order_Quantity', 'sum'),
    line_count=('Sales_Doc', 'count')    # Modified this line so the provided data sets can be used.   Thanks @Timus
).reset_index()

# Compute rolling statistics and 3-sigma for each SoldTo group
grouped['avg_line'] = grouped.groupby('SoldTo')['line_count'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean())
grouped['ma_qty'] = grouped.groupby('SoldTo')['total_quantity'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean())
grouped['stDev_of_qty'] = grouped.groupby('SoldTo')['total_quantity'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3, min_periods=1).std(ddof=0))
grouped['stDev_of_lines'] = grouped.groupby('SoldTo')['line_count'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3, min_periods=1).std(ddof=0))

# Compute the 3-sigma thresholds
grouped['avg_qty_sigma_trigger'] = ((3 * grouped['stDev_of_qty']) + grouped['ma_qty'])
grouped['avg_line_sigma_trigger'] = ((3 * grouped['stDev_of_lines']) + grouped['avg_line'])

# Function to identify atypical rows based on 3-sigma rule within each SoldTo group
def identify_atypical(df):
    atypical_indices = []

    for sold_to, group in df.groupby('SoldTo'):
#        group = group.reset_index(drop=True) # Removed this line. Thx @Timus
        
        for i in range(len(group) - 1):
            current_row = group.iloc[i]
            next_row = group.iloc[i + 1]

            if (next_row['line_count'] > current_row['avg_line_sigma_trigger'] or
                next_row['total_quantity'] > current_row['avg_qty_sigma_trigger']):
                atypical_indices.append(group.index[i + 1])

    # Mark atypical rows in the dataframe
    df['is_atypical'] = False
    df.loc[atypical_indices, 'is_atypical'] = True

    return df, atypical_indices


# Identify atypical rows
grouped, atypical_indices = identify_atypical(grouped)

# Print the dataframe and indices of atypical rows
print("Atypical rows indices:", atypical_indices)
print("")

print(grouped)

# Filter atypical rows within a specified date range
#check_these = grouped[(grouped['is_atypical'] == True) & (grouped['Created_on'] >= '2024-06-01')]
check_these = grouped[(grouped['is_atypical'] == True) & (grouped['total_quantity'] != 1) & (grouped['line_count'] != 1) ]
#check_these = grouped[(grouped['is_atypical'] == True)]

# Save the cleaned dataframe to a CSV file
check_these.sort_values(by='SoldTo', ascending=True).to_csv('order_behavior_analysis_3.csv', index=False)


When Using this data, having only a single Soldto, the code returns results as needed:
Atypical rows indices: [5, 6, 11]
[['SoldTo', 'Created_on', 'Sales_Doc', 'Order_Quantity'],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-02 00:00:00'), 110866572, 4],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-02 00:00:00'), 110866572, 4],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-02 00:00:00'), 110866572, 2],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-02 00:00:00'), 110866572, 2],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-02 00:00:00'), 110866572, 17],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-06 00:00:00'), 110884032, 4],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-06 00:00:00'), 110884032, 2],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-06 00:00:00'), 110884032, 11],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-06 00:00:00'), 110884032, 6],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-06 00:00:00'), 110884032, 4],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-06 00:00:00'), 110893468, 11],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-06 00:00:00'), 110893468, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-07 00:00:00'), 110902368, 33],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-07 00:00:00'), 110902525, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-07 00:00:00'), 110902525, 4],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110929917, 8],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110929917, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110929917, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110929917, 6],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 16],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 20],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 20],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 4],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 1],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 20],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 8],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 3],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-13 00:00:00'), 110966070, 52],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-15 00:00:00'), 111035845, 15],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-16 00:00:00'), 111177113, 18],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-16 00:00:00'), 111177113, 5],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-16 00:00:00'), 111177887, 20],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-16 00:00:00'), 111177887, 11],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 4],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 8],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 20],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 22],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 4],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 16],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 12],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 20],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 18],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 3],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 18],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 20],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 7],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 22],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-21 00:00:00'), 111446837, 9],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-21 00:00:00'), 111446837, 13]]


But using this data, having (2) SoldTo values, the code returns new rows, but no longer "detects" the known atypical rows and reports back different indices:
Atypical rows indices: [1, 6, 12, 14, 17, 5, 6, 11]
[['SoldTo', 'Created_on', 'Sales_Doc', 'Order_Quantity'],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2023-01-13 00:00:00'), 108036530, 10],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2023-01-13 00:00:00'), 108036530, 1],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2023-03-03 00:00:00'), 108391209, 20],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2023-03-03 00:00:00'), 108391209, 2],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2023-04-13 00:00:00'), 108738953, 30],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2023-07-24 00:00:00'), 109827151, 20],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2023-09-20 00:00:00'), 110467726, 30],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2023-10-11 00:00:00'), 110658107, 10],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2023-11-10 00:00:00'), 110946376, 2],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2023-11-10 00:00:00'), 110946376, 3],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2023-11-10 00:00:00'), 110946376, 5],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2023-12-13 00:00:00'), 111681360, 5],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2023-12-19 00:00:00'), 111739909, 6],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2023-12-19 00:00:00'), 111739909, 4],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2023-12-19 00:00:00'), 111739909, 2],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2023-12-19 00:00:00'), 111739909, 2],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2024-01-25 00:00:00'), 112057996, 5],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2024-02-23 00:00:00'), 112322261, 12],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2024-03-07 00:00:00'), 112453024, 5],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2024-03-25 00:00:00'), 112625572, 5],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2024-03-25 00:00:00'), 112625572, 3],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2024-03-27 00:00:00'), 112651496, 2],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2024-04-26 00:00:00'), 112942567, 5],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2024-04-26 00:00:00'), 112942567, 5],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2024-04-26 00:00:00'), 112942567, 2],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2024-04-26 00:00:00'), 112942567, 2],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2024-04-26 00:00:00'), 112942567, 2],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2024-05-09 00:00:00'), 113200232, 2],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2024-05-22 00:00:00'), 113359192, 2],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2024-06-10 00:00:00'), 113534221, 1],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2024-06-10 00:00:00'), 113534221, 34],
 ['56619720', Timestamp('2024-06-10 00:00:00'), 113534221, 20],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-02 00:00:00'), 110866572, 4],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-02 00:00:00'), 110866572, 4],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-02 00:00:00'), 110866572, 2],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-02 00:00:00'), 110866572, 2],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-02 00:00:00'), 110866572, 17],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-06 00:00:00'), 110884032, 4],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-06 00:00:00'), 110884032, 2],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-06 00:00:00'), 110884032, 11],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-06 00:00:00'), 110884032, 6],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-06 00:00:00'), 110884032, 4],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-06 00:00:00'), 110893468, 11],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-06 00:00:00'), 110893468, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-07 00:00:00'), 110902368, 33],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-07 00:00:00'), 110902525, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-07 00:00:00'), 110902525, 4],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110929917, 8],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110929917, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110929917, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110929917, 6],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 16],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 20],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 20],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 4],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 1],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 20],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 8],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-09 00:00:00'), 110930046, 3],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-13 00:00:00'), 110966070, 52],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-15 00:00:00'), 111035845, 15],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-16 00:00:00'), 111177113, 18],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-16 00:00:00'), 111177113, 5],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-16 00:00:00'), 111177887, 20],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-16 00:00:00'), 111177887, 11],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 4],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 8],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 20],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 22],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 4],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 16],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 12],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 20],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 18],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 3],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 18],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 20],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 7],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 10],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-20 00:00:00'), 111430236, 22],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-21 00:00:00'), 111446837, 9],
 ['59908158', Timestamp('2023-11-21 00:00:00'), 111446837, 13]]

Thanks for help interpreting my path forward.

It's really hard to say, given that there's no sample data to run this on. But what caught my attention was the following constellation in the function identify_atypical: df gets grouped, then for each group the index is reset group = group.reset_index(drop=True), then those new indices get collected atypical_indices.append(group.index[i + 1]), and finally with those new indices the original dataframe is adjusted df.loc[atypical_indices, 'is_atypical'] = True. That looks like a recipe for disaster.

Additionaly: it seems to me that the task in identify_atypical would be better done with native Pandas methods (use .shift) instead of looping over rows (for i in range(len(group) - 1) ...).

Thanks, @Timus.  I think you're on to something...   my code features a mobius strip of index resetting ...   Also, are you able to load the sample datasets I provided in a list format from my post? Is there a better way to furnish that data here? <- thanks again for help/comments.

Yes, I can load the samples, but they aren't enough to run your code: the column Material is missing, which means I can't build grouped as shown, and therefore not all statistics can be calculated, and so identify_atypical can't be run.

If you remove this group = group.reset_index(drop=True) line from the function, the results should be consistent (they are at least here, with a reduced form of the dataframe).

@Timus.  That's very insightful.   Your suggestion to drop that group = line is what straightened out the issue for me.   Also, I'm going to update my syntax above to remove the 'Material' field in place of another field in the data sets provided which will render the the line_count as needed.   Thanks also for pointing that out. Hat-tip!

@Timus: I've modified my syntax to reflect your suggestions & will test another couple hours.  Will come back soon to mark your suggestions as the answer.

As I have written in the comments, I am pretty sure that the resetting of the group indices in the function identify_atypical is messing up the final update of the orignal dataframe. So I'd suggest that you try something like the following:
def identify_atypical(df):
    atypical_idxs = set()
    for _, group in df.groupby('SoldTo'):
        m = (
            group['line_count'].gt(group['avg_line_sigma_trigger']).shift())
            | group['total_quantity'].gt(group['avg_qty_sigma_trigger'].shift())
        )
        atypical_idxs.update(group[m].index)
    return df.assign(is_atypical=df.index.isin(atypical_idxs)), atypical_idxs

(I can't run a full test because the sample is incomplete, but on a reduced dataframe it looked fine.)

Thanks @Timus.  I've updated the syntax so it'll work with the sample in case this solution is also helpful to someone else in the future.
